# MongoDB match based on type string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm Nodejs beginner, I want to match weight to be based on cargoType

I have tried something like that, I know it's incorrect but you can see from this what I want.

```
 const cargoQuery = Cargo.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $cond: {if: {cargoType: {$eq: "special"}}, then: {weight: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleMaxWeightADR}}}
    },
    $match: {
      height: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleHeight},
      width: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleWidth},
      clength: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleLength},
      
  }},
  { $lookup: {
    from: Load.collection.name,
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "cargoId",
    as: "loads"
  }
  },
  {
  $lookup: {
    from: UnLoad.collection.name,
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "cargoId",
    as: "unLoads"
  }
},
{
  $sort : {
    date : -1
  }
}
  ]);
```

I'm recieving tRuleMaxWeightSPECIAL from Frontend and it's sucessfuly loaded.

I want to display all Cargos that has weight which is different but based on cargoType.
Do i need conditional statement $cond or there is another way to solve this? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: please post some example document and expected result in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to match the additional criteria with the value(s) of the string:

```
{$match: {
      $or: [
         {cargoType: "special", weight: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleMaxWeightADR}}
         {cargoType: {$ne: "special"}}
      ],  
      height: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleHeight},
      width: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleWidth},
      clength: {$lte: +req.query.tRuleLength},      
}},
```